# Tensorflow could not initialize the libcurl library on Mac OS

Tags: tensorflow, libcurl

I have build up the WebAPP of this [Project](https://github.com/BrainPad/FindYourCandy) on Mac OS using conda and tensorflow v0.12.1. It work so well still I try to train, tensorflow show this error message:

> W tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/google_auth_provider.cc:151] All
>   attempts to get a Google authentication bearer token failed, returning
>   an empty token. Retrieving token from files failed with "Failed
>   precondition: Could not initialize the libcurl library. Please make
>   sure that libcurl is installed in the OS or statically linked to the
>   TensorFlow binary.". Retrieving token from GCE failed with "Failed
>   precondition: Could not initialize the libcurl library. Please make
>   sure that libcurl is installed in the OS or statically linked to the
>   TensorFlow binary.".

Logs：

```
2018-04-03 09:33:49,154 - candysorter.views.api - INFO - === Start training: id=9120093671565748, session=20180403_093211_9120093671565748 ===
2018-04-03 09:33:49,154 - candysorter.views.api - INFO - Creating labels file: job_id=candy_sorter_20180403_093211_9120093671565748
2018-04-03 09:33:49,184 - candysorter.views.api - ERROR - Unexpected error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wubinbin/anaconda3/envs/candy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/wubinbin/anaconda3/envs/candy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/wubinbin/Developer/FindYourCandy/webapp/candysorter/views/api.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wubinbin/Developer/FindYourCandy/webapp/candysorter/views/api.py", line 337, in train
    candy_trainer.create_labels_file(job_id, labels)
  File "/Users/wubinbin/Developer/FindYourCandy/webapp/candysorter/models/images/train.py", line 76, in create_labels_file
    f.write(json.dumps(labels, separators=(',', ':')))
  File "/Users/wubinbin/anaconda3/envs/candy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 150, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/Users/wubinbin/anaconda3/envs/candy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 182, in close
    pywrap_tensorflow.Set_TF_Status_from_Status(status, ret_status)
  File "/Users/wubinbin/anaconda3/envs/candy/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/Users/wubinbin/anaconda3/envs/candy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
FailedPreconditionError: Could not initialize the libcurl library. Please make sure that libcurl is installed in the OS or statically linked to the TensorFlow binary.
```

Comment: So, is "libcurl installed in the OS or statically linked to the TensorFlow binary"?

Comment: I have installed libcurl，but I don't know how to linke it to the TensorFlow binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use TF1.7.0 instead of TF0.12.1, and fix this problem. But I still don't know what happen in TF0.12.1.